# API endpoint parameters for annual and quarterly data: NASDAQ API

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, nasdaq-api

I'm trying to use the endpoint to filter between quarterly and annual financial data (balance sheets, income & cash flow statements).

As of now the following endpoint: 'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/AAPL/financials?' only shows the annual data, but I also need to get the quarterly data too.

Does anyone know what would be **the correct parameter to include in this endpoint?** I've tried searching through the documents however this endpoint itself is not found anywhere but still works upto date (I was shown this endpoint by someone so I do not know the source of where it is found).

The documents in the NASDAQ data link do not provide the endpoint I'm using nor did their customer service help with identifying it. It is a valid endpoint though.

my python code below:

```
import requests
import json

api = 'my_api_key'
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'origin': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.nasdaq.com',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

api_url = f'https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/AAPL/financials?&api_key={api}'

data = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers).json()


with open("nasdaq_financials.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```